# Exception Value:too many values to unpack during django login

Tags: python, django, exception, authentication

I have django login view/functionality that was working fine until now, but suddenly when i am trying to login with the Admin account with username and password(which was working without any error previously) it was telling me the  below error

```
ValueError at /login/
too many values to unpack
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8006/login/
Django Version: 1.3.1
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    too many values to unpack
Exception Location: /home/rick/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py in check_password, line 42
Python Executable:  /home/rick/.virtualenvs/project/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.4
Python Path:[....]
```

My view is something like below

```
def blogin(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EmailLoginForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid(): ...
            ult = UserLoginTrail(\
                user = User.objects.get(username=request.POST['username']),
                login_time = datetime.datetime.now(),
                )
            ult.save()
        .......
        .......
```

So i have tried to change the password from shell and also by using management commands that django provides like below

Management Command

```
python manage.py changepassword rick@gmail.com
```

Shell

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
user = user.objects.get(username='rick@gmail.com')
user.set_password('password')
user.save()
```

But still i am getting the same error when trying to login with my username `rick@gmail.com` ?

So how to avoid this `too many values to unpack` error, and why it is occurring suddenly ?

Answer (score 0):

That exception means that you are trying to unpack a tuple, but the tuple has too many values with respect to the number of target variables.

So your error is in the function `check_password` in the models. Check your parameters, your inputs, your returns. For example this raises an error very simillar with yours and can guide you to the solution to your problem:

```
def returnATupleWithThreeValues():
    return (1,2,3)
a,b = returnATupleWithThreeValues()
print a
print b
```

EDIT: if this does not help you, please provide your `check_password` function and the place where you are calling it

Comment: `check_password` is the default django method right ?, i din't customized it.

Comment: oh, true, sorry. I thought you built your own auth. Do you get the same error if you use username=form.cleaned_data['username'] , isntead of username=request.POST['username']